# Logging array mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, console.log

Has anyone seen an error with console.log(array) where the number of objects found in the array and the actual objects in array do not match? See attached screenshot where it says there are 2 objects in the array but it has a length of 18.[image]

Comment: Looks like you're a victim of [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2408-chrome-dev-tools-live-update-in-the-javascript-console-is-confusing.htm)?

Comment: Wow ok, I had no idea that console.log was async in Chrome. That explains a lot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Objects are (re-)evaluated at the time of inspection in the Chromium dev tools console, so if you want to see a snapshot view of an object, you should serialize it at the time you log it (using e.g. `JSON.stringify(array, null, 2)`) or spread all values into new objects recursively, etc (e.g. `console.log([...array.map(obj => ({...obj}))])`).